# Parse Server issue viewing relations

Tags: parse-platform, parse-server

I'm running `parse-server` version 4.4.0 and I'm trying to create a new `_Role` object using `parse-dashboard` and PostgreSQL. I can successfully create the `_Role` object but I cannot view the `users` relations. When I click on the button "View relation" in the `users` column I get a blank screen.

I've dug into the PostgreSQL logs and I'm seeing this:

```
SELECT * FROM "_Join:users:_Role" WHERE "owningId" = 'I2GKNd41kM';
SELECT * FROM "_User" WHERE "objectId" IS NULL ORDER BY "name" ASC LIMIT 200;
ERROR:  column "name" does not exist at character 250
```

And this is a valid error, the "name" column does not exist on the `_User` table.

However, viewing the `roles` relation works as expected and the logs look like this:

```
SELECT * FROM "_Join:roles:_Role" WHERE "owningId" = 'I2GKNd41kM';
SELECT count(*) FROM "_Role" WHERE "objectId"  IN ('FOOwXF4Rxa');
```

I cannot figure out how `parse-server` is generating that SQL in the error case above. I'm at a complete loss and would appreciate any pointers or other places to look. I clearly have something misconfigured but I can't seem to find it anywhere.

Comment: It's definitely something misconfigured (perhaps something I did manually by accident?) - I tried creating another column on `_Role` with a relation on `_User` and viewing that relation fails to open also. In fact, any relation added to `_Role` other than pointing to `_Role` is failing...

Comment: Ok, after more digging, I created a relation on `ClassA` called "users". Then I populated the relation. Then I sort one on column "foo" while viewing the relation. Then I press the "back" button to view my `ClassA` objects. Parse appears to be trying to sort on "foo" from within `ClassA` now and thus generates the error.